# Unable to run Anbox snap on fresh installed Ubuntu 21.10 -(binder trouble)

Tags: snap, anbox

To reproduce. install anbox `snap install --devmode --edge anbox`
In my case, I installed on a fresh installed Ubuntu 21.10

Then I discovered that the binder module was not working as expected.
Anbox devs could not figure this out:  https://github.com/anbox/anbox/issues/1949

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working using the [Liquorix kernel](https://liquorix.net) on Pop!_OS 21.10. Liquorix packages the `binder` module, whereas the Ubuntu kernel doesn't seem to.

I don't remember how I came across this as a solution, but I'll update this answer if I come across it again.